# Power USB at certain CPU temperature

Tags: cpu, fan, temperature, cpuinfo

I have an unusual server set-up. Basically, I have a combination of salvaged parts from 3 Powerbook G4s running a non-graphical distribution of lubuntu. Problem is, I'm better with hardware than the software side of things.

I'm powering a USB fan (as all other connectors are gone) that I want to turn on when the CPU reaches a certain temperature. Eventually I'll install a proper temperature sensor, but for now that will have to do.

I'm sure there's a simple script I could write for this which could run in the background monitoring the temperature and enabling power to the USB port. Any ideas? Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you could turn on/off your fan by running the following command:

```
# turn off
echo suspend > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/power/level

# turn on
echo on > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/power/level
```

replace `usbX` with `usb1`, `usb2` or whatever

then you would have to check the temperatur periodically, for example by running a script every minute using cron job. You can take a look at [this german article](https://jkhofmann.wordpress.com/2012/03/11/linux-cpu-temperatur-uberwachen/) to see how to implement it. Don't worry if you do not speak german. The bash script from the example is pretty easy to understand without the surrounding text.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks heaps for your help. You're a life saver. Your example worked off the bat. Thank you :)